# How to add interactive links on Mermaid flowchart edges?

Tags: mermaid

https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/flowchart.html indicates how to add interactive links (urls) on nodes, but it is silent about edges.

One solution would be a create nodes for edges and render a single "interactive link" as 2 links and a node. Any smarter way? Thanks for help